# Bidding + Shopping Cart: Open source CMS or Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, open-source

I am planning a web application for **Bidding + Shopping Cart**.

Users can add products/auction(Seller) and buy/place bid(buyer). Admin control it all.

Is there any good open source **CMS** available for this in PHP (apart from drupal)?

Or should I go for **Zend Framework** to build it from scratch?

What will be the good approach?

Comment: I think you be use wordpress with woo-commerce shopping cart plugin using avada theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok!! Its near about one month and no answer so for...

But I am glad that I found a better solution for this. Thanks to Magento!

**Magento** is way better than any other open source web shops available for this type of requirement.

And as it is based on Zend framework which is familiar to me, I thought working in it will be easy.